# Priority Queue Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

Am implementing the A* algorithm based on this tutorials:

```
create the open list of nodes, initially containing only our starting node
   create the closed list of nodes, initially empty
   while (we have not reached our goal) {
       consider the best node in the open list (the node with the lowest f value)
       if (this node is the goal) {
           then we're done
       }
       else {
           move the current node to the closed list and consider all of its neighbors
           for (each neighbor) {
               if (this neighbor is in the closed list and our current g value is lower) {
                   update the neighbor with the new, lower, g value 
                   change the neighbor's parent to our current node
               }
               else if (this neighbor is in the open list and our current g value is lower) {
                   update the neighbor with the new, lower, g value 
                   change the neighbor's parent to our current node
               }
               else this neighbor is not in either the open or closed list {
                   add the neighbor to the open list and set its g value
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Now i have two priority Queues for the open list and the closed list.

After moving a node from the open list to the closed list, i must generate its neighbours and check them one by one if they are also in the closed list and perform an operation as described above. The problem is i can only peek() only the head of the queue and compare to the generated neighbours. I can't access the rest of the nodes in the queue in order to compare them as well.

My questions is:

how can i compare the neighbours to the nodes in the closed list. Or should i use a different data structure for the closed list?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store a value on each node that indicates if it is in the open list, closed list, or no list, then you don't have to go through the lists to see if it is or not.

And, as others have pointed out, you will probably get best results from implementing your own heap, as java's implementation apparently lacks the ability to update the key value on a node.

Comment: Highly inefficient. The iterator doesn't return the elements in order, so you are condemned to an O(n squared) comparison.

Comment: What will be the best option?

Comment: @EJP How is the order of the lists relevant? You seem to be implying that the order is somehow important, but I think any method involving traversal of the lists would be highly inefficient. See above for another method.

Comment: @EJP And where does the O(n^2) come from? It's O(n).. None of what you said seems to make any sense.

Comment: @EJP You might want to read up on big O notation, specifically the complexity of finding an item in an unsorted array: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Comment: @AnthonyBlake: for each element: check if it already exists, `1 + 2 + ... + n = (n^2)/2 = O(n^2)`.

Comment: @amit Uhh, no -- only the neighbors are checked against the lists.. this is O(n * m), and because the number of neighbors (m) is a small constant, it is O(n)

Comment: @AnthonyBlake: to be more accurate, it is `O(B^d * B) = O(B^(d+1))` where `B` is the [branch factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor), and `d` is the solution's depth, while it can be done in `O(B* log(B^d)) = O((B^2)*d)`, which is much better.

Comment: @amit True, but I was only explaining why O(n^2) was wrong. Searching the heap isn't as good as storing a value on each node to indicate which heap it is in (or if it isn't in a heap). That is O(1), which is much better.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake: But modification itself using the iterator is `O(B^(d+1))`, cannot be avoided, while it can be done in `O(B* log(B^d)) = O(B*log(B)*d)` [fixed math error from previous comment for last equation]. It significantly slows A* run [I know that as a fact, I experimented both these solution about half a year ago, in Python though...]

Comment: @amit Yes, I was about to point out the error =) The question was "how can i compare the neighbours to the nodes in the closed list.", and for that, you don't need to traverse list/heap at all. But yes, you cannot avoid updating values in the heap, which is O(log n) (branching factor should be disregarded, it is lower order)

Comment: @amit Python isn't exactly known for high-performance =) I implemented A* in C for a topological autorouter a few years ago.. N was huge and performance was important. I can't remember too much, but this has jogged my memory as to some of the tricks =)

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue's main disadvantage is it is only guarantees "what is the first element", no guarantees on any other elements [except they are "bigger" then the first], so finding an element is an expansive operation.

You can use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to store your states, and then finding the elements will be done in `O(logn)` time, instead the `O(n)` PriorityQueue offers. You can use the [first()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first%28%29) method to get the first [lowest] element. To modify an element, you will need first to remove the original [will probably require an additional `HashMap:State->value` to store the current value] and then to insert the new node, with its modified value

Note that you will probably have to rewrite `equals()` for your nodes.

Also note:Though both are `O(logn)`, each insert operation in a `TreeSet` is usually slower then its equivalent in `PriorityQueue`, so if your problem doesn't have to reopen states, this solution can actually be slower. However, in the general case, this is expected to be faster then the alternative, due to the shortened seek time.

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of your search space? If it's a path though a grid, you can use a grid to find a node "by positions". To update the F cost of the "potentially re-parented node" that is on the open-list you need operations that Java's standard PriorityQueue class does not support (namely UpdateKey, and the nodes have to know their index in the heap so UpdateKey can find them), so you'd have to roll your own heap (which is relatively easy).